# How do I reset cash and gap progress?

Tags: tony-hawks-downhill-jam

I recently bought a used copy of Tony Hawk’s Downhill Jam for DS. However, some progress from the previous owner carried over even after starting a new save file. Gaps are shown as completed on stages I haven’t played yet and some skateshop items have already been purchased.

How do I fully reset my progress and start fresh?